# Picasso Android image loading - threading model

Tags: android, multithreading, picasso, okhttp, image-loading

Here is what i did:

- Created a custom downloader (`extends OkHttpDownloader`) and assigned it to Picasso.
- Inside the downloader, i added an interceptor ( `getClient().interceptors().add(new Interceptor() {...}`)

I launched my Android app in debug mode, i noticed there are two threads, each appropriately named "Picasso-....".  When i try to access an image from the web,  each of these threads calls the `public Response intercept(Chain chain)` method of my interceptor, meaning that the same request is processed by **more than one** thread simultaneously. What's the reason behind this?

Comment: can we see the relevant code?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Gavriel for getting me to do something as simple as setting up a very rudimentary Picasso setup and actually do my homework, i.e. experiment with it a bit. Anyhow. I discovered that doing:

`picasso.setIndicatorsEnabled(true);` and/or `picasso.setLoggingEnabled(true);`

actually created another thread (for I guess managing this kind of debug info?). This was confusing the hell out of me - the two threads really do execute my request once each. Very confusing, but whatever. I guess it's done asynchronously, would make sense for the logging anyway.  Any idea, though, why that second thread would execute my image request?